# Qlik Sense extension Backend Api undefined

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to develop an extension for Qlik Sense. I would want to use the `Backend API` but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectValues' of undefined

```js
node.on("click", function(d){
    this.backendApi.selectValues(0,[1,2],true);
});
```

Where's my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case `this` will be executed in the context of the html element (`node`) and the html element dont have `backendApi` method. So the error is "correct"

Somewhere in your code (above this part of the code) you can define new variable that is the real Qlik context. And then use it inside the click event. Something like this:

```js
paint: function ($element, layout) {
  var qlikContext = this;

  // ... more code here eventually

  node.on("click", function(d){
    qlikContext.backendApi.selectValues(0,[1,2],true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is work well. What can I write if I want to select integer values and I dont know thier indexes in the field array.

Comment: for Capability API you can use the [Field API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2021/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/qlik-field-interface.htm) to select without index